# Clear the value of a select when the value of the first select changes

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, select, react-select

I need help, I have 2 `Select` from `react-select`, the first is the name of a spare, and the second is the model of said spare. When changing the name of the spare, the `Select`  options of the spare model change to those of said part.

**Problem:**
The problem I'm having is that when I change the spare Name Selection I want the spare Model Selection to be cleared.

First I have the two main variables of this problem
One to save the model options and the other to display the default Model `Select` value.

```
const [opModels, setOpModels] = useState(
    Array.from({ length: spareQuantity }, () => [])
  );
  const [selectedModels, setSelectedModels] = useState([]);
```

Then we have the function to handle the change of the `Select` name.
with `setOptSelectSpare` I load the selected option into a variable.
with `setSelectedIndex`  I load the index of the dynamically created form.

With the last three lines, I make the Select value null.

With this I want that when the `handleSelectChange`  function is loaded, that is, when the user changes the name of the model then the `Select` value of the models is cleared of the previously selected option if it was selected.

But this is not the case, the model options are loaded according to the name of the spare part, but the Select value of the models remains null even if you try to select the options.

```
  const handleSelectChange = (selectedOptionSpare, index) => {
    setOptSelectSpare(selectedOptionSpare)
    setSelectedIndex(index)

    const updatedSelectedModels = [...selectedModels];
    updatedSelectedModels[index] = null;
    setSelectedModels(updatedSelectedModels);
  };
```

In useEffect we create and filter the models by name, and save them in the first variable and then add them to the Select model option.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (optSelectSpare) {
      const name = optSelectSpare.label
      if (objetSpare) {
        const filteredSpares = objetSpare.filter((s) => s.name === name);

        const spareModelsOptions =
          filteredSpares.map((s) => ({
            label: s.model,
            value: s.id,
          }));

        const updatedOpModels = [...opModels];
        updatedOpModels[selectedIndex] = spareModelsOptions;
        setOpModels(updatedOpModels);
        

      }

    } else {
      const updatedOpModels = [...opModels];
      updatedOpModels[selectedIndex] = [];
      setOpModels(updatedOpModels);
    }
  }, [optSelectSpare, objetSpare, opModels, selectedIndex])
```

Finally I have the rendering of the components, where the small forms are created for each spare part, here the values, functions and options are added to each selection.

```
{Array.from({ length: spareQuantity }, (_, index) => (
                    <div key={index} className="select-input-container">
                      <label>Name</label>
                      <Select
                        options={option}
                        onChange={(selectedOption) => handleSelectChange(selectedOption, index)}
                        value={nameSpare[index]}
                        className="select-spacing"
                        placeholder={`Nombre del repuesto ${index + 1}`}
                        name={`spareName${index}`}
                        styles={customStyles}

                      />

                      <label>Model</label>
                      <Select
                        options={opModels[index]}
                        value={selectedModels[index]}
                        className="select-spacing"
                        placeholder={`Modelo del repuesto ${index + 1}`}
                        name={`spareModel${index}`}
                        styles={customStyles}

                      />

                      <label>Spare part serial number {index + 1}</label>
                      <input type='text' className='numSeries' name={`spareSeries${index}`} />

                    </div>
                  ))}
```

I would be very grateful if someone could help me with this confusion.